# How to convert byte array to string excluding 0x00 chars in Android

Tags: android, arrays, string, byte

the result of my decryption routine returns a byte array like this:

30303030303030310000000000000000

That should be converted to (int) 00000001, but I cannot get rid of the trailing 0x00's. What would be the best way to accomplish that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So if it isn't 1 make it 0 and drop the trailing 0's? So 3031100 would be 00011?

Comment: Nope, let me rephrase: I have this 16-byte array [0x30 0x30 ... 0x31 0x00 0x00...]. 0x30 is the ASCII '0', 0x31 is '1'... If I simply issue ...new String(myBytes) and try to convert it to int, I get:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "00000001����������������"

Comment: Thanks zgc7009, got it the dirty way, but working for now:

public static String bytesToString(byte[] data) {
    String dataOut = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != 0x00)
            dataOut += (char)data[i];
    }
    return dataOut;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the workaround for trimming the trailing 0x00's in the byte array (replace or trim won't work):

```
public static String bytesToString(byte[] data) {
    String dataOut = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != 0x00)
            dataOut += (char)data[i];
    }
    return dataOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the replace method?

```
String foo = new String(myBytes);
foo = foo.replace((char)0, ''); // Character with zero

Integer result = Integer.valueOf(foo);
```

Or even better, a Regular Expression that filters the String, getting rid of anything out of the 0-9 range.

```
String foo = new String(myBytes);
foo = foo.replace((char)0, ''); // Character with zero

Integer result = Integer.valueOf(foo);
```

Comment: String.replace does not accept '' as second parameter. You may want to check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007352/how-to-detect-end-of-string-in-byte-array-to-string-conversion

Comment: Thanks for the link Raghu, that would work but I found another solution, with less workarounds, just below.